# jQuery toggle divs and hide divs

Tags: php, jquery, toggle, show

I need some help, i have a forum page and i cant get the toggle part to work

Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function(event) {
        $("#div").hide();
        var tmp = ($("#div" + $(this).attr("target")).is(":visible") ? false : true)
        if (tmp) $("#div" + $(this).attr("target")).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<h2>Forum</h2>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" class="table">
<tr style="background: #f2f2f2;"><td><strong>Name</strong></td><td></td></tr>
<tr style="display:none;" id="divDynamicID"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NAME</td><td align="right" width="40"><img src="../img/pencil.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="../img/delete.png"></td></tr>';
<tr class="Test"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Name</td><td align="right" width="40"><img src="../img/pencil.png" class="button" target="dynamicID">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="../img/delete.png"></td></tr>';
```

When you click the .button i want it to hide all open divs and just open that one you click at, but at this time i only get the show part to work not the not show part.

Comment: Your code doesn;t have any `divs` apart from `<div class="alert alert-box alert-error">`. And I am pretty sure you didn;t mean that one.

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery code I found code with `#div`, but **could not find div** with id div in HTML code. ***# will only be used with id of the HTML control***

Whereas div is the selector used for HTML controls

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about your question. If I've understood properly I'd say two things. First, you can have a local variable for the tr id which you want to display. I guess the id is the value of the target attribute for button class with "div" prefixed. And secondly, you can have a class for each of the rows so that you can hide them all when needed.

```
echo '<tr style="display:none;" id="div'.$obj->boardID.'"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$obj->name.'</td><td align="right" width="40"><img src="../img/pencil.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="../img/delete.png"></td></tr>';
echo '<tr class="Test"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$obj->name.'</td><td align="right" width="40"><img src="../img/pencil.png" class="button" target="'.$obj->boardID.'">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="../img/delete.png"></td></tr>';
```

In the abodes, I put a class trClass. You can change it to whatever you feel contextual to your code.

```
$(".button").click(function(event) {
    $('.trClass').hide();
    var trId="div"+$(this).attr("target");
    var tmp = $("#" + trId).is(":visible");
    if (tmp) $("#" + trId).show();
});
```

Comment: My jQuery script works right now to show the tr's but not to hide them, and i should only be able to show one row at the time so the other hides (IF they are opened). If you still dont understand i try to explain a little better :)